# aws iam - prevent iam group or account from provisioning any services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to use AWS Budget to avoid different departments over utilizing AWS resources, and I am wondering if I can prevent them from provisioning any new resource once their AWS Budget limit has reached. Is it possible through IAM policy, or SCP to prevent an account, or an IAM group from provisioning any new resources in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a usable IAM classification for actions which provision new resources?

No, I do not think so. IAM provides so called *Access Levels* to classify different types of IAM actions in the AWS Management Console. [1]
However, I could not find any possibility to reference them via an IAM Action policy document. [2]
There are some patterns in the action names for each AWS service [3] that you could use to reference actions with access level *Write*, e.g. `ec2:Create*` [4]. Unfortunately there are some patterns which are more subtle such as `ec2:Run*`.

Furthermore, the fact that an IAM action is classified with access level *Write* does not mean that it creates new resources or causes additional costs, e.g. `ec2:Delete*` removes certain resources which generally does not incur additional costs.

A workaround would be to identify all actions which are potentially increasing costs (e.g. by provisioning new resources) manually using the respective service's IAM reference table [3].

#### How to block specific IAM actions using SCP if budget threshold for account is breached?

If you have a list of actions you want to block after the budget limit was reached, you could do this as follows:

1. Create an SNS topic and configure AWS Budgets to publish to that topic once the given threshold is reached. [5][6]
2. Use CloudWatch Events to trigger a Lambda function which uses the AWS SDK to attach an SCP to the account which breached the threshold. You do this by creating an SCP which denies all action that you identified previously as "budget increasing" / "resource creating". You attach that SCP as a "Deny List" [7], i.e. in addition to the existing *FullAWSAccess*-SCP.
3. Create a CloudWatch Events Rule that triggers on a schedule [8], i.e. once at the beginning of each month (or whenever the start of your budget's period is set). That rule calls a Lambda function which uses the AWS SDK to remove the previously attached SCP from the account.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_understand-policy-summary-access-level-summaries.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_action.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html
[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-sns-policy.html
[6] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-create.html (Nr. 16)
[7] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/SCP_strategies.html ("Using SCPs as a Deny List")
[8] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html